# How to get test value from CDATA in xml file using java

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing, cdata

I'm trying to get the **MethodName** value from the CDATA node in xml file.
**XML file looks like-**

```
<params>
            <param index="0">
              <value>
                <![CDATA[{PackageResponse=./src/test/resources/TestData/ExpectedData/InstantCash/GetAnywherePayoutAgents/ExpectedPackageResponse.json, ProviderRequest=./src/test/resources/TestData/ExpectedData/InstantCash/GetAnywherePayoutAgents/ExpectedProviderRequest.json, ParameterFilePath=./src/test/resources/TestData/RequestParameter/InstantCash/GetAnywherePayoutAgents.json, ProviderResponse=./src/test/resources/TestData/ExpectedData/InstantCash/GetAnywherePayoutAgents/ExpectedProviderResponse.json, MethodName=GetAnywherePayoutAgents}]]>
              </value>
            </param>
          </params>
```

What i have tried is only giving me all text value of this-
**JAVA Code-**

```
public static String getCharacterDataFromElement(Element e) {

        NodeList list = e.getChildNodes();
        String data;

        for(int index = 0; index < list.getLength(); index++){
            if(list.item(index) instanceof CharacterData){
                CharacterData child = (CharacterData) list.item(index);
                data = child.getData();

                if(data != null && data.trim().length() > 0)
                    return child.getData();
            }
        }
        return "";
    }
```

But i want only methodName value from CDATA. Please help!

Comment: The obvious suggestion is to use standard syntax (XML or JSON) for the value, rather than something you've made up. But if you must use a non-standard syntax, then you're just going to have to do some custom parsing.

Comment: Your entire getCharacterDataFromElement method can be replaced with the [getTextContent](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.xml/org/w3c/dom/Node.html#getTextContent%28%29) method, which Element inherits from Node.  The text content itself looks like unquoted JSON, so you should pass it to a JSON parser, then retrieve the value corresponding to the `"MethodName"` key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already have method for retrieving CDATA content. To extract MethodName or other fields from this text there can be implemented custom parsing function, e.g.:

```
public static String getMethodName(String source, String fieldName) {
        if(source.startsWith("{") && source.endsWith("}")) {
            source = source.substring(1, source.length() - 1);
        }
        return Arrays.asList(source.split(",")).stream()
                .map(s -> s.trim().split("="))
                .filter(s -> fieldName.equals(s[0]))
                .map(s -> s[1])
                .findFirst()
                .orElse(null);
}
```

It splits text by commas, than splits each token by equal signs, than searches for supplied field name and returns text after equal sign (or null if not found). It can be called as follows:

```
String cdata = getCharacterDataFromElement(element);
String methodName = getMethodName(cdata , "MethodName");
```

Comment: Thanks @Daniil it's working, but for lambda expression we need Java8 or above.